# number of row that repeated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, sql-server-express

table `tbl1`

field `id,name`

id=1   name=a

id=1   name=a

id=1   name=w

id=1   name=f

id=2   name=c

id=2   name=a

how can get number of field repeated. id=1 ,name=a  ==>2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simple

```
select
  id,
  name,
  count(*)
from
  table
group by
  id, name
```